# How to programmatically execute undo and redo in CKEDITOR, and reset their stacks?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, undo, redo

Is there a way to programmatically execute undo and redo in CKEDITOR?

And the other question is: is there a way to reset the undo stack and also the redo stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undo:

```
editor.execCommand( 'undo' );
```

Redo:

```
editor.execCommand( 'redo' );
```

Reset:

```
editor.resetUndo();
```

Comment: Is there also a way to reset only the Redo part of the undo stack?

Comment: Nope. I mean... everything is doable, but you would have to check the [undoManager](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/undo/plugin.js) code. There's no public API for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the suggest about undoManager code ;)